# Layout invisible, button up on him

Tags: android, android-layout

(i have put the code at the end of my post)

i would like to make a hidden menu.

I don't know if i take the good way.

I have some button visible, some invisible button and at the an another visible button.
One of the button in first layout have to set visible the hidden buttons.

I would like to have the last button just after the first bunch.
But like i have put invisible the Layout so i have an empty space.

I would like when i pressed the button for set visible that the last button go down.

I hope you will understand want i want to do and what i have done.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@drawable/fond"
   >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/top" 
        android:layout_gravity="top" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
    />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/fond2"
        >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" 
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"

            >
            <LinearLayout 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="3"
                >
                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/button_garçon"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Bg"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_purple" 
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:onClick="actionGarçon"
                />
                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/button_mixte"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Bm"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_purple" 
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:onClick="actionMixte"
                />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_fille"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Bf"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_purple" 
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:onClick="actionFille"           
                />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="1"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_param"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Bp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_green" 
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:onClick="actionParametre"           
                />
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- invisible -->
            <LinearLayout 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Tq" 
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                />
                <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/Emc"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                />
                 <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Tpre"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                />
                <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/Epre"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Tsuf" 
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                />
                <EditText 
                    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/Esuf"
                    android:singleLine="true" 
                />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Tl"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                />
                <LinearLayout 
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" 
                    android:weightSum="100"
                    >

                    <Button android:id="@+id/button_court"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/Blc" 
                            android:layout_weight="25"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_purple"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff" 
                            android:onClick="actionCourt"
                    />
                    <Button android:id="@+id/button_moyen"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/Blm" 
                            android:layout_weight="25"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_purple"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff" 
                            android:onClick="actionMoyen"
                    />
                    <Button android:id="@+id/button_long"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/Bll"
                            android:layout_weight="25" 
                            android:background="@drawable/button_purple"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:onClick="actionLong" 
                    />
                    <Button android:id="@+id/button_tous"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/Blt"
                            android:layout_weight="25" 
                            android:background="@drawable/button_purple"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:onClick="actionTous" 
                            android:state_pressed="true"
                    />
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button android:id="@+id/button_orig"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/Bo"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_purple" 
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:onClick="actionOrigine"
                />
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- /invisible -->
            <Button android:id="@+id/button_recher"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Br"
                android:background="@drawable/button_green"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:onClick="actionRecherche"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>      
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to use `android:visibility="gone"` so that what ever you set to `"gone"` does not occupy any space on the layout.

Basically, instead of `android:visibility="invisible"` you should use `android:visibility="gone"`

See if that works.

Comment: Oh sorry i miss this. I'm tired and i think i really need at least a paused. I have the feeling to be silly right now.